# Deflation in Eigen value and vector computation (Power method )

Tags: matlab, debugging, math, signal-processing

I have the following (edited) code for computing all the Eigen values and vectors of a small matrix using the power series method (by deflation technique):

```
function [eigvect,eigval]=eigen2(A,x0,nit)
% calculates the largest eigenvalue and corresponding eigenvector of
% matrix A by the power method using x0 as the starting vector and
% carrying out nit interactions.
%
eigval=0;
siz=size(A);
siz=siz(1);
for m=1:siz
x = x0;t=x0;
for n = 1:nit
xnew = A*x;
lambda = norm(xnew,inf);
tnew=transpose(A)*t;% computing left eigenvectors
x1=x;
x=xnew/lambda;
x2=x;
t1=t;
t=tnew/lambda;
t2=t;
end
x = x/(norm(x)); %normalise x
t=t/(norm(t));
eigvect(:,m)=x;
eigval(m)=lambda;
teigvect(:,m)=t;
% eigvect
Anew=A-x*transpose(x)*A*x*transpose(x);
A=Anew;
fprintf('\n lambda= %f',lambda);
end
teigvect
fprintf('n = %4d normalised x = %g %g %g\n', n, x');
% eigval
%end
```

The function calculates the eigen values correctly but not the corresponding eigen vectors for the non-dominant eigenvalues.

Can someone point where the error is?

**EDIT1**: Since the right and left eigen vectors are equal in a symmetric matrix, I am not involving the left eigen vector in the computation of Anew.

**Test cases:**

Computed using matlab's in-built eigen function:

```
A=[ 2 1 2; 1 2 1; 2 1 2];

[v,d]=eig(A)

v =

    0.7071    0.3251    0.6280
    0.0000   -0.8881    0.4597
   -0.7071    0.3251    0.6280

d =

   -0.0000         0         0
         0    1.2679         0
         0         0    4.7321
```

**Result of the eigen2 function:**

```
[r,s]=eigen2(A,[3 7 8]',100)

 lambda= 4.732051
 lambda= 1.267949
 lambda= 0.000000
r =

    0.6280   -0.3251    0.7071
    0.4597    0.8881         0
    0.6280   -0.3251    0.7071

s =

    4.7321    1.2679    0.0000
```

Comment: Please document one of your test cases that went wrong, together with the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the power method, no power series here.

---

One obvious problem is that you assume that the left eigenvector is equal to the right eigenvector. This is only true for symmetric (and normal) matrices. If you use any other matrix, it is a wonder that the eigenvalues are computed correctly.

Comment: Could you please mention the lines of the code that do so? Would be quite helpful.

Comment: `Anew=A-lambda*x*transpose(x);`, the second `x` should be a left eigenvector `y`, with `transpose(y)*A=lambda*transpose(y)`. Or you aim for a Smith (?) normal form, then the eigenvectors have to form an orthonormal basis and your form of deflation applies.

Comment: Hello. For the time being, I have  considered a symmetric matrix as the input and yet not obtaining the correct answer. I'm not able to figure out the error either. I've documented the answer along with the test case. The vectors differ by a negative sign.

Comment: The full vector changing sign is ok, you are computing  a basis for the eigenspace. Check the matrix after the second reduction, it could be too reduced.

Comment: The following matrix is used to obtain the third eigenvector: 

A=

1.0e-016 *

  [  0.8327         0    0.8327; 
         0         0         0 ;
    0.8327         0    0.8327;]

Moreover,the third eigen vector is obtained as:[ 0.707 0 0.707] while the correct value is [0.707 0 -0.707]

I am wondering what went wrong there.

Comment: For symmetric matrices you need to enforce that the iteration vectors are and remain orthogonal to the previous eigenvectors. Your last matrix is, up to rounding noise, the zero matrix and has the full space as eigenspace.

Comment: For the eigenvectors computed by the built-in  eig function,
The dot product between the vectors yeild the following result:
`[v,d]=eig(A)

v =

    0.7071    0.3251    0.6280
    0.0000   -0.8881    0.4597
   -0.7071    0.3251    0.6280

v(:,1).*v(:,2)

ans =

    0.2299
   -0.0000
   -0.2299

v(:,3).*v(:,2)

ans =

    0.2041
   -0.4082
    0.2041
v(:,3).*v(:,1)

ans =

    0.4440
    0.0000
   -0.4440`

For the eigenvectors generated by the eigen2 function,

`[r,s]=eigen2(A,[3 7 8 ]',100)

r =

    0.6280   -0.3251    0.7071
    0.4597    0.8881         0
    0.6280   -0.3251    0.7071`

Comment: Continued:
`r(:,1).*r(:,2)

ans =

   -0.2041
    0.4082
   -0.2041

>> r(:,1).*r(:,3)

ans =

    0.4440
         0
    0.4440

>> r(:,2).*r(:,3)

ans =

   -0.2299
         0
   -0.2299`

These are the values that I get.

Comment: You should not use the component wise product, but the scalar or dot product which is the sum over all the component products.

Comment: To complete my comment from yesterday: Since the exact matrix is the zero matrix, and the algorithm finds the largest eigenvalue, as long as noise is present, this largest eigenvalue and the connected eigenvector will be determined by the noise. In some sense this is similar to a division by a near-zero.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions.